# Nobody can access the page of my site

Tags: apache-2.2

I installed the Apache. I created a directory with the name of my site:

```
/var/www/domain
```

and I configured the virtualhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ServerName www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access domain.com, the content appears not from the directory `/var/www/domain`, but from `/var/www`.

Why?

---

The problem was solved!
Just add:

```
<directory /var/www/domain/htdocs>
    Options -Indexes
</directory>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: From the looks of it you've set '/var/www/incoreside' as the document root, but uploaded the content of your website to '/var/www/domain'. Unless of course you've forgotten to replace incoreside with domain in your example?

Comment: When I put the archives of my site in the paste '/var/www/domain'. The site no appears.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after making changes to your virtual hosts file?

Comment: Restart apache.

Comment: I already did this.

Comment: Have you got any files in /var/www/?

Comment: No. The files is on /var/www/domain.

Comment: And your domain is not misspelt in your host file? Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html for examples.

Comment: The my config of VirtualHost, this of according the examples. See my topic.

Comment: The my domain acess only by: www.domain.com/domain. The alright, is access by www.domain.com

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your last comment. Is www.domain.com working but www.domain.com/domain isn't? Or the other way around?

Comment: Are there any other `DocumentRoot` directives? Like in the Global Configuration??

Comment: One possibility is that the default VirtualHost block still exists (or some other conflicting VirtualHost). Use `httpd -S` to see how Apache parsed your configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the correct [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: Can you provide some details of what a "correct NameVirtualHost directive" may look like in the OP's config?

Comment: `NameVirtualHost *:80`